# opengl multitexturing is wiping out my scene!

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to implement alpha masking using opengl and multitexturing. I've an alpha image (it's RGB with no data in the alpha channel) and another image (also RGB no alpha) I'd like to mask with the alpha image. I'm using quads in the scene a ground and background quad and then a quad which represents the entity I'm trying to mask.

When I "turn on" the multitexturing code, the ground and background quads are wiped off the screen. I do see the foreground quad with image image and it's masked correctly. When I turn off the multitexturing code, the scene renders as expected, but that removes the foreground object and image (along with multitexturing).

I modified my alpha mask and found out, the multitexturing code is drawing a huge plane (inspite of my uv coordinate calculations and glVertex3f calls) with the original image and the alpha map. I kind of get the impression OpenGL is ignoring my glVertex3f call.

I've had to change GL_SOURCE0_RGB to GL_SOURCE1_RGB b/c if I don't do that I get really strange behavior from the video card (foreground object renders but the mask isn't applied and gets turned into a grey quad on the right side of the screen with a funky projection applied to it). I've tested this on 2 systems and it's the same behavior in both cases.

i'm attempting to use a fixed pipeline multitexturing technique.

```
GLuint alphaGLTexture; 
SDL_SurfaceToGLTexture(aTexture, &alphaGLTexture);

GLuint fgGLTexture;
SDL_SurfaceToGLTexture(fgTexture, &fgGLTexture);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, alphaGLTexture);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE1_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_REPLACE);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fgGLTexture); 

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE1_RGB, GL_PREVIOUS);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE2_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_RGB, GL_ALPHA);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_MODULATE);

glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

double u_coord = 0.0f, v_coord = 0.0f;

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, u_coord, v_coord);
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, u_coord, v_coord);
glVertex3f(posax, posay, posaz);

u_coord = 1.0f; v_coord = 0.0f;
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, u_coord, v_coord);
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, u_coord, v_coord);
glVertex3f(posbx, posby, posbz);

u_coord = 1.0f; v_coord = 1.0f;
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, u_coord, v_coord);
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, u_coord, v_coord);
glVertex3f(poscx, poscy, poscz);

u_coord = 0.0f; v_coord = 1.0f;
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, u_coord, v_coord);
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, u_coord, v_coord);
glVertex3f(posdx, posdy, posdz);

glEnd();

glLoadIdentity();
```

The function, SDL_SurfaceToGLTexture, works consistently for the ground and background quads.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without seeing the actual code. After all you omited the whole part where u_coord, v_coord change

Comment: they're using the same coordinates, each modification, that portion of the code is consistent with other areas, for the sake of time, i just added in some hard coded values.

Comment: without knowing what the TexEnv settings are and how your blending is set up, there's just no way to know what happens.

Comment: I modified the question slightly  and added the fixed functions for TexEnv, sorry about all that!

Answer (score 2):

You bind the alpha texture to `GL_TEXTURE0` and the foreground texture to `GL_TEXTURE1`. But when drawing you set texture coordinates for `GL_TEXTURE1` and `GL_TEXTURE2`. Is this intended or could it be your problem?

**EDIT:** Are you sure you have disabled texturing for all units except the ones used when rendering the background quads. And also keep in mind, that the texture environment is per-unit state and not per-texture state, so you also have to restore it when using texturing on the background quads.

Chris's solution is related to this. Just keep in mind that OpenGL is a state machine and when not resetting the active texture unit, all following texture operations apply to `GL_TEXTURE1` and when not disabling texturing for the unused units, all following objects (even in the next frame, of course) will be drawn multitextured.

Comment: Looking at the code again, I agree that this seems very suspicious and is likely the issue.

Comment: I'm a bit of a knuckle head I'll fix that portion of the code in the example, I was testing something out and failed to copy the source code properly to SO. My only issue at this point is that after multi texturing everything behind the foreground plane is really dim - I turned off GL_LIGHTING, is this a by product of using multitexturing?

Comment: Multi-texturing shouldn't in general make things darker. It all depends on the texture environment (and the inputs to it).

Comment: @ct Updated my answer (if the question is still of interest).

Answer (score 1):

After setting up the texture environment for the second level, try calling "glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);" again. I've seen much weirdness when I've forgotten to reset the texture level back to GL_TEXTURE0.

Also, scatter some calls to glGetError() after every few OpenGL calls to see if something innocent looking has an error.

Comment: thanks, so far it's "getting there". I switched back to using GL_TEXTURE0 and GL_TEXTURE1. I call glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) prior to glBegin(GL_QUADS) and the code is now rendering the ground and background quads along with the foreground quad. the ground and background are completely grey (untextured) and the foreground quad is texture with the alpha mask...but it's still rendering the entire image on an object of size greater than the one defined by my glVertex3f calls. I think i'm on the right track. i'll post after more experimentation. i'll give glGetError() a shot next.

Comment: Another useful technique is to use coloured textures with a single pixel edge along the border (such as a red texture with a blue border). Experimenting with blending textures like that (no alpha) can give you a good sense of if the textures are placed / blending as you they they should. Also, I suggest making all the same glTexEnv calls for both texture levels to ensure there isn't any weird state state for the wrong texture level (and verify the default values for what you don't set are expected).

Comment: I did some additional fiddling yesterday and got the ground, background, and foreground object quads to render! The only issue I see at this point is that the ground and background quads are tinted darker than the foreground object quad. I think it's probably a blending issue (I'm not blending at the moment). I'll see about updating the code in a bit, thanks so much for the guidance @chris-mennie! The Red Book really doesn't do this particular subject much justice.

Comment: Glad to be of some assistance. Answer upvotes are always appreciated :P.

Comment: Is there a reference in the red book/literature/or in some documentation about resetting the active texture level to GL_TEXTURE0 prior to rendering the polygons? That might be helpful figuring out this dimness issue with the background and ground planes being darker than the foreground object plane (up vote made!) quick update: I used alpha blending on the foreground object plane and it's clearing out the black borders just fine. Still having issues with the textures behind the foreground element being really dark compared to their previous appearance (minus a foreground element).

Comment: or could it be an issue with drawing order of the textures? if i render the texture first and then the alpha mask?

Comment: @ct Of course the drawing order counts. You probably need to adjust your texture environment settings when changing the texture application order. For example the `GL_PREVIOUS` input to the combiner refers to the output of the previous texture stage or the fragment's color if on stage 0, be it computed by lighting or just by coloring.